# Deleted Table Control leads to run time error

Tags: abap, dynpro

I have a screen with one table control which displayed values from my internal db.
It worked out flawlessly.

I added another table control which didn't worked out the way i wanted.

I deleted the control `CONTROLS: tc_two TYPE TABLEVIEW USING SCREEN 9000.`

And now I'm getting a runtime error `CONTROL-Variable not found`.

> Q: What happens if i declare new Controls? Where do they get implemented?

I tried to debug my code and the error appears at `CALL SCREEN 9000.`

Here is the full code:

```
REPORT zsch_test.

CONTROLS: tc_one TYPE TABLEVIEW USING SCREEN 9000.

DATA: it_uebung  TYPE TABLE OF zsch_uebung,
      ok_code    TYPE sy-ucomm,
      fill       TYPE i.

TABLES zsch_uebung.

DATA: lines TYPE i,
      limit TYPE i.

SELECT * FROM zsch_uebung INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE it_uebung WHERE status = '1'.

CALL SCREEN 9000.

MODULE status_9000 OUTPUT.
  SET PF-STATUS 'STATUS9000'.
*  SET TITLEBAR 'xxx'.
  DESCRIBE TABLE it_uebung LINES fill.
  tc_one-lines = fill.
ENDMODULE.

MODULE fill_table_control OUTPUT.
  READ TABLE it_uebung INTO zsch_uebung INDEX tc_one-current_line.
ENDMODULE.

MODULE cancel INPUT.

  LEAVE PROGRAM.

ENDMODULE.

MODULE read_table_control INPUT.
  lines = sy-loopc.
  MODIFY it_uebung FROM zsch_uebung INDEX tc_one-current_line.

ENDMODULE.

MODULE user_command_9000 INPUT.
  ok_code = sy-ucomm.
  CASE ok_code.
    WHEN 'EXIT'.
      LEAVE PROGRAM.
    WHEN OTHERS.
  ENDCASE.
ENDMODULE.
```

Screen 9000:

```
PROCESS BEFORE OUTPUT.
MODULE STATUS_9000.
LOOP WITH CONTROL TC_ONE.
MODULE fill_table_control.
ENDLOOP.

PROCESS AFTER INPUT.

MODULE cancel AT EXIT-COMMAND.

LOOP WITH CONTROL TC_ONE.
MODULE read_table_control.
ENDLOOP.
MODULE USER_COMMAND_9000.
```

[image]

Thanks!

sadly it's in german[image]

Comment: Again: Show us the entire problem, not just some fragment. Try to put yourself in someone else's position - "I did something, then changed something, now it no longer works, where's the problem?"

Comment: I would like to understand what happens if i declare new controls. If someone could tell me the answer i can fix it :). I cant find any left over code from my control: tc_two. That's why i thought there is more than just the code i usually work with.

Comment: There certainly is - the screen definition (which is more than the processing logic), and you haven't added that to the question (yet) - please do so.

Comment: What do you mean by "screen definition"?

Comment: The attributes and the element list.

Comment: Done :). I know i should write my code in one language and dont mix it up.

Comment: And what exactly is the error message? Please not some approximation, but the literal message.

Comment: Okay that's weird. I just executed the program and I didn't get the error message? I didn't change anything.

Comment: @vwegert Is there a way how I can display previous error messages?

Comment: try transaction ST22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the fact that the problem disappeared apparently without further action, one might assume that this was either a buffer issue (which is why you should re-start the entire transaction when testing a changed program) or you accidentally failed to activate the entire program (and, for example activated only the report source, but not the screen definition).

Comment: If I'll run into this problem again I'll restart the transaction. Thanks for your help!